# Coinbase API Market Cap End Point

Tags: cryptocurrency, coinbase-api

I've been browsing over the references of the coinbase API and the coinbase pro API and I am not able to find an endpoint for market cap. However, were I to log into Coinbase and check BTC for example I would see that Coinbase displays a market cap.

Is this a calculation done via an API? Or is it an end point? Any help would be appreciative!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the coinbase api doesn't have an endpoint for market cap. I don't think I've even seen supply data available to make the calculation. I'm sure the coinbase app is doing it's own calculations for market cap.

coinMarketCap.com has an api that includes all that though.

https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest